# Poisson: distribution of $N(u)$, given that $N(t)=n$, for $0\leq u \leq n$

Tags: probability

What is the distribution of $N(u)$, given that $N(t)=n$, for $0\leq u \leq n$

---

**Attempt:**

The Conditional Distribution of Arrival Times is:

$n!/t^n$.

I guess $N(u)$should be in the form of binomial with $n\choose k$$(k/u)^k(1-k/u)^{n-k}$.

Comment: And what is preventing you to compute $P(N(u)=k\mid N(t)=n)$, exactly?

Comment: Check to see whether my logic is correct, (without actually computing it).

Comment: I updated my answer. As Professor Didier points out, I made an incorrect assertion. I was ***thinking*** of the difference, but I wrote the conditional distribution. In other words, I swapped $-$ with $|$, big difference. Logically, it is incorrect, but the calculation and the result I had in mind are the same.

Comment: @randy Sorry but I cannot "check your logic", not seeing where it is in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$\{N(u) = k, N(t) = n\}\iff \{N(u) = k, N(t)-N(u) =n-k\},$$
$N(t)-N(u)\sim\text{Pois}((t-u)\lambda)$, and that $N(u)$ is independent of $N(t)-N(u)$.

Then we proceed as usual, assuming some $\lambda >0$,
\begin{align*}
P(N(u)=k|N(t) = n)&=\frac{P(N(u) = k,N(t) = n)}{P(N(t) = n)}\\
&=\frac{P(N(u) = k, N(t)-N(u) =n-k)}{P(N(t) = n)}\\
&=\frac{P(N(u) = k)P( N(t)-N(u) =n-k)}{P(N(t) = n)}\\
&=\frac{e^{-u\lambda}\frac{(u\lambda)^k}{k!}\cdot e^{-(t-u)\lambda}\frac{[(t-u)\lambda]^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}}{e^{-t\lambda}\frac{(t\lambda)^n}{n!}}\\
&=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{u^k(t-u)^{n-k}}{t^k\cdot t^{n-k}}\\
&=\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{u}{t}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{u}{t}\right)^{n-k}.
\end{align*}